# Print last occurrence of a tag in a log file using awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk

We need to do some monitoring of a large log file to find the last line that a tag (in this case a currency pair) appeared.

Log looks like this:

```
20141217-10:34:48.411: 8=FIX.4.2^A35=X^A56=ABCD_MD^A55=AUD/USD^A15=USD^A279=2^A269=1.245
20141217-10:34:48.415: 8=FIX.4.2^A35=X^A56=ABCD_MD^A55=GBP/AUD^A15=GBP^A279=2^A269=1.245
20141217-10:34:48.465: 8=FIX.4.2^A35=X^A56=ABCD_MD^A55=AUD/NZD^A15=AUD^A279=2^A269=1.245
20141217-10:34:48.466: 8=FIX.4.2^A35=X^A56=ABCD_MD^A55=EUR/NZD^A15=EUR^A279=2^A269=1.245
20141217-10:34:48.466: 8=FIX.4.2^A35=X^A56=ABCD_MD^A55=AUD/USD^A15=AUD^A279=2^A269=1.245
20141217-10:34:48.507: 8=FIX.4.2^A35=X^A56=ABCD_MD^A55=GBP/AUD^A15=CAD^A279=2^A269=1.245
20141217-10:34:48.526: 8=FIX.4.2^A35=X^A56=ABCD_MD^A55=AUD/USD^A15=EUR^A279=2^A269=1.245
20141217-10:34:48.528: 8=FIX.4.2^A35=X^A56=ABCD_MD^A55=USD/CAD^A15=USD^A279=2^A269=1.245
20141217-10:34:48.529: 8=FIX.4.2^A35=X^A56=ABCD_MD^A55=AUD/CAD^A15=AUD^A279=2^A269=1.245
20141217-10:34:48.544: 8=FIX.4.2^A35=X^A56=ABCD_MD^A55=EUR/AUD^A15=EUR^A279=2^A269=1.245
20141217-10:34:48.546: 8=FIX.4.2^A35=X^A56=ABCD_MD^A55=EUR/NZD^A15=USD^A279=2^A269=1.245
20141217-10:34:48.554: 8=FIX.4.2^A35=X^A56=ABCD_MD^A55=GBP/AUD^A15=GBP^A279=2^A269=1.245
20141217-10:34:48.563: 8=FIX.4.2^A35=X^A56=ABCD_MD^A55=AUD/USD^A15=CAD^A279=2^A269=1.245
20141217-10:34:48.563: 8=FIX.4.2^A35=X^A56=ABCD_MD^A55=EUR/NZD^A15=EUR^A279=2^A269=1.245
20141217-10:34:48.563: 8=FIX.4.2^A35=X^A56=ABCD_MD^A55=GBP/AUD^A15=AUD^A279=2^A269=1.245
20141217-10:34:48.563: 8=FIX.4.2^A35=X^A56=ABCD_MD^A55=EUR/NZD^A15=CHF^A279=2^A269=1.245
20141217-10:34:48.607: 8=FIX.4.2^A35=X^A56=ABCD_MD^A55=EUR/NZD^A15=CAD^A279=2^A269=1.245
20141217-10:34:48.615: 8=FIX.4.2^A35=X^A56=ABCD_MD^A55=GBP/AUD^A15=EUR^A279=2^A269=1.245
20141217-10:34:48.616: 8=FIX.4.2^A35=X^A56=ABCD_MD^A55=AUD/USD^A15=AUD^A279=2^A269=1.245
```

which matches the pattern:

```
\d{8}-\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d.*35=X.*\w{3}/\w{3}
```

where

```
The date:                        \d{8}-\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d
Denotes a price message:         35=X
A currency pair e.g. AUD/USD:    \w{3}/\w{3}
```

(Regex syntax is probably different in awk)

Would be great to have an awk script which outputs the last pricing message (line containing 35=X) for each currency pair, and the timestamp that was at the start of that line.  E.g.

```
20141217-10:34:48.529 AUD/CAD
20141217-10:34:48.465 AUD/NZD
20141217-10:34:48.616 AUD/USD
20141217-10:34:48.544 EUR/AUD
20141217-10:34:48.607 EUR/NZD
20141217-10:34:48.615 GBP/AUD
20141217-10:34:48.528 USD/CAD
```

The logs are naturally date ordered.  So I'd just need the last line per currency pair.  There would not need to be any sorting done on the actual date string.

The logs are very large.  Easily over 1GB.

Any help would be *greatly* appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: And you expect others to think and create that `awk` script?

Comment: I reply myself: "Yes, others have thought and created the `awk` script. The author of this question had not to learn any `awk` nor type a single line of code. That's amazing.

Comment: I didn't provide any code because I had no idea even where to start on this problem.  The generous people who have answered my question have really helped me with the problem and have helped be better understand awk.  I even posted back a suggested improvement on one answer once I got testing with it.  But yeah, thanks for the downvote. Awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is far more memory efficient than the other answers and maintains order

```
tac test | awk 'match($0,/A55=([^^]+)\^/,a)&&!b[a[1]]++{print $1,a[1]}' | tac
```

It reverses the file and pipes into awk, which prints the last(now first) occurence of each currency, then pipes back into tac to restore original order

OP suggested this is quicker than the match

```
tac test | awk -F' |=|\\^A' '$5=="X"&&!a[$9]++{print $1,$9}' | tac
```

Comment: If it is a small file then small memory overhead won't matter but if it is huge file then calling `tac` twice on input file is no way efficient as it will slow down whole file processing.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the script:

```
awk -F' |=|\\^A' '{a[$9]=$1 " " $9} END{for(var in a)print a[var]}' File
```

Here we assign `space` and `=` and `^A` as delimiters. Then `1st` field will be time and `9th` field will be your `currency pair`. With this `9th` field as index, build up the array `a` (fill array with `1st` field and `currecny pair`, latest values will be taken as the previous entry for the same index will be overwritten. Then in the `END` block, go through the array and print the `array element`.

**Output:**

```
SO$ awk -F' |=|\\^A' '{a[$9]=$1 " " $9} END{for(var in a)print a[var]}' File
20141217-10:34:48.528: USD/CAD
20141217-10:34:48.615: GBP/AUD
20141217-10:34:48.544: EUR/AUD
20141217-10:34:48.529: AUD/CAD
20141217-10:34:48.607: EUR/NZD
20141217-10:34:48.465: AUD/NZD
20141217-10:34:48.616: AUD/USD
```

Comment: Why save the array index again as part of the array content instead of just `{a[$9]=$1}...print a[var],var`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk -F ': |[=^]' '{a[$9]=$1} END{for (i in a) print a[i], i}' file.log
20141217-10:34:48.615 GBP/AUD
20141217-10:34:48.528 USD/CAD
20141217-10:34:48.465 AUD/NZD
20141217-10:34:48.529 AUD/CAD
20141217-10:34:48.616 AUD/USD
20141217-10:34:48.607 EUR/NZD
20141217-10:34:48.544 EUR/AUD
```

**This will change the order of output. If you want to maintain original order then use:**

```
awk -F ': |[=^]' '!a[$9]{b[++n]=$9} {a[$9]=$1}
          END{for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[b[i]], b[i]}' file.log
20141217-10:34:48.616 AUD/USD
20141217-10:34:48.615 GBP/AUD
20141217-10:34:48.465 AUD/NZD
20141217-10:34:48.607 EUR/NZD
20141217-10:34:48.528 USD/CAD
20141217-10:34:48.529 AUD/CAD
20141217-10:34:48.544 EUR/AUD
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.  There was not much in it.  Cheers.

Comment: (sorry I meant not much between yours and the other here, both great answers)

Comment: Slight differences, if you are okay with trailing colon in first column output and don't care about original order of records.

Comment: The second one is upside down from original.

Comment: That's not correct, 2nd command shows unique records as per their appearance in file. For ex: record of `EUR/AUD` comes last in the file.

Comment: The last line is `AUD/USD` which is now at the top

Comment: `AUD/USD` is in the very first line in the file and hence first line in input.

Comment: `20141217-10:34:48.616` is on the last line though, so it being at the top makes it upside down :)

Comment: OP's requirements are: **which outputs the last pricing message (line containing 35=X) for each currency pair**. So in different words my awk command grabs unique currency pair (key) as in the original order of input but it grabs **very last** value for each key. Hope it is clear now.